# Array where the length is variable

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an array where the length is variable.
My idea (It doesn't work and it's ugly):

```
    int y = 7-getY();   
    Point[] punkte = new Point[y];              
    Point punkt = new Point(getX(), getY()+y);

         if(y==1){
            punkte[0]=punkt;                            
            return punkte;
            }

        if(y==2) {
            punkte[0]=punkt;
            punkte[0]=punkt2;
            return punkte;
        }

        if(y==3) {
            punkte[0]=punkt;
            punkte[0]=punkt2;
            punkte[0]=punkt3;
            return punkte;
        }
        if(y==4) {
        punkte[0]=punkt;
        punkte[0]=punkt2;
        punkte[0]=punkt3;
        punkte[0]=punkt4;
        return punkte;
    }

    if(y==5) {
        punkte[0]=punkt;
        punkte[0]=punkt2;
        punkte[0]=punkt3;
        punkte[0]=punkt4;
        punkte[0]=punkt5;
        return punkte;
    }

    if(y==6) {
        punkte[0]=punkt;
        punkte[0]=punkt2;
        punkte[0]=punkt3;
        punkte[0]=punkt4;
        punkte[0]=punkt5;
        punkte[0]=punkt6;
        return punkte;
    }

    if(y==7) {
        punkte[0]=punkt;
        punkte[0]=punkt2;
        punkte[0]=punkt3;
        punkte[0]=punkt4;
        punkte[0]=punkt5;
        punkte[0]=punkt6;
        punkte[0]=punkt7;
        return punkte;
    }
```

I think you understood my code so far. There is definitely a way that is easier, shorter and more beautiful to write, but I just can not get it ...
(Code is welcome).

Comment: What do you mean by "where the array length is a variable?" The length of an array is a number, but you can store this number in a variable if you wish. There is generally no need, because you can write `punkte.length` to get the length anyway.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise in creating a dynamically sized array that you have to implement yourself? If not, just use `ArrayList`, that's exactly what `ArrayList` does.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but you are repeatedly reassigning `punkte[0]`. That, of course, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is (IMO) the "classic" example of fall-through being useful in `switch` statements (see also [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)).

```
int y = 7 - getY();
Point[] punkte = new Point[y];
Point punkt = new Point(getX(), getY() + y);
// ...
switch(y) {
case 7: punkte[6] = punkt7;
case 6: punkte[5] = punkt6;
case 5: punkte[4] = punkt5;
case 4: punkte[3] = punkt4;
case 3: punkte[2] = punkt3;
case 2: punkte[1] = punkt2;
case 1: punkte[0] = punkt;
}
return punkte;
```

Alternatively, use a `List<Point>`.